# What is the purpose of embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = false on salesforce communities?

Tags: community, liveagent, lightning-community, chat, snap-ins

What is the purpose of embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = false on salesforce communities?

Is there a way to create a custom help button that initiates an embedded service chat session?

I just don't understand why that would be an option on the community component if it wasn't possible to somehow trigger chat in another way.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm kind of late with this answer, but the solution to your problem is explained here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_bootstrap_chat.htm

Basically, calling `embedded_svc.bootstrapEmbeddedService()` from your custom button's `onclick` event will trigger the chat window.

Setting `embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = false` will prevent the default chat button from being displayed

Hope this helps.